# Why do all high level players drive a Nissan Silvia?

Tags: need-for-speed-world

I play Need for Speed World and I noticed that every high level player drives a Nissan Silvia which is a tier 1 car and has low points either for speed, handling and acceleration? I do not understand why they drive and how they win with that car.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Need for Speed wiki](http://nfs.wikia.com/wiki/Nissan_Silvia_%28S15%29):

> The S15 is one of the best, if not,
>   the best drift car in the whole Need
>   for Speed series. However due to its
>   handling and acceleration the S15 is
>   also recommend in circuit and/or
>   sprint races. In NFS:World the S15
>   always has been the overall best
>   performing in T1. Players also have
>   stated that the Silvia can easily keep
>   up with T2 cars.

Comment: Yeah. The S15 has been my T1 car and I loved it... except for a couple of facts. Driving a T1 car gets you smaller rewards than you'd get otherwise and heat 5 is very very hard to escape with this car without resorting to instant cooldown. That's why I'm currently grinding money with the Supra... for the only purpose to recoup money and buy something _else_ than that POS.

Comment: the link is dead blog review!