# Which is the best T3 car which can be bought without boost in Need for Speed World?

Tags: need-for-speed-world

I play Need for Speed World and I want to have some list of cars but I can not find any.  In [Why do all high level players drive a Nissan Silvia?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/22904/why-do-all-high-level-players-drive-a-nissan-silvia) some rating is mentioned, but even on the blog I can not find a list of T3 cars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lexus LFA for 2000000 IGC.

It is currently the best car

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit? Why is it the best car?